# How do I check if the username value is already in the database in visual basic?

Tags: mysql, database, ms-access, visual-studio-2017

```
Private Sub SignUpBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SignUpBtn.Click
    'ttp://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/visual-basic-net/7258/adding-and-saving-records-access-database-using-vbnet.html
    Try

        cm = New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        With cm
            .Connection = cn
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users (UserName,UserPassword) VALUES (@Uname,@Pword)"



            .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@UserName", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255, Me.Uname.Text))
            .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@UserPassword", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255, Me.Pword.Text))

            Me.Uname.Text = MainClass.consoleout

            ' RUN THE COMMAND
            cm.Parameters("@UserName").Value = Me.Uname.Text
            cm.Parameters("@UserPassword").Value = Me.Pword.Text


            cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Record saved.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            Dim Form1 As New Form1
            Form1.Show()
            Hide()

            Exit Sub
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I'm trying to make this form with a check that if the username entered is the same as a username in the database. Currently I can save any user over and over again and the record is just repeated in the database. My username text box is called Uname and my password text box is called Pword. The database table is called Users and the columns I trying to put them is called UserName And UserPassword. My database connection has already been declared in the Module. I got all of the coding for this from a website(http://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/visual-basic-net/7258/adding-and-saving-records-access-database-using-vbnet.html). I just modified it to suit my conditions. If someone could tell me how to make sure that no 2 usernames are saved in the database I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Add a (or rather: the missing) *unique index* on the field *Uname*.

Then catch and handle the error when attempting to insert a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

make UNAME as primary key 
and in code put try catch